# Getting an error as Batch update returned unexpected row count from update

Tags: hibernate

I am getting the below error with my code.

```
Hibernate: insert into EMPLOYEE (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, SALARY, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: update CERTIFICATE set ID=? where ID=?
org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:63)
```

Here is my code.

Employee.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
   private int id;

    @Column(name="FIRST_NAME")
   private String firstName; 
    @Column(name="LAST_NAME")
   private String lastName;   
    @Column(name="SALARY")
   private int salary;


    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID")
     @OrderBy("name ASC")
   private SortedSet<Certificate> certificates;
//getters and setters
```

}

Certificate.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CERTIFICATE")
public class Certificate implements Comparable <Certificate>{

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
       private int id;
    @Column(name="CERTIFICATE_NAME")
       private String name; 
    //generate getters and setters
   }
```

I am trying to add users using below code.

```
ManageEmployee ME = new ManageEmployee();
      /* Let us have a set of certificates for the first employee  */
      TreeSet set1 = new TreeSet();
      set1.add(new Certificate("MCA"));
      set1.add(new Certificate("MBA"));
      set1.add(new Certificate("PMP"));

      /* Add employee records in the database */
      Integer empID1 = ME.addEmployee("Manoj", "Kumar", 4000, set1);
```

and with my addEmployee method I have below code

```
Employee employee = new Employee(fname, lname, salary);
         employee.setCertificates(cert);
         employeeID = (Integer) session.save(employee);
```

Please suggest what I should be changing from my end to get this fixed.

Comment: Share your hibernateconfig xml file

Comment: How do you save `CERTIFICATE` entities? Did  you miss cascading `certificates` collection?

Comment: Here is my hibernateconfig 
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        
        <mapping class="com.insubuy.model.Address"></mapping>
        <mapping class="com.insubuy.model.Customer"></mapping>
        <mapping class="com.insubuy.model.Policy"></mapping>
        <mapping class="com.insubuy.model.Employee"></mapping>
        <mapping class="com.insubuy.model.Certificate"></mapping>
        
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>

Answer (score 0):

The issue was because of the id attribute not being set by default. I had to update my code to include GeneratedValue annotation and that fixed the issue.

```
   @Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ID")
   private int id;
```